# Checking to see if a specific song is playing in xna

Tags: c#, xna

I wish to know if it is possible to check if a specific song is playing in XNA, what I want to do is something like

```
if(stateS == "normal")
        {
            if(MediaPlayer.IsPlaying(song1)
            {
               //do nothing  
            }
            if(!MediaPlayer.IsPlaying(song1)
            {
               //play song 1 
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(norm, pos, Color.White);
        }
        if(stateS == "fast")
        {
            if(MediaPlayer.IsPlaying(song2)
            {
               //do nothing  
            }
            if(!MediaPlayer.IsPlaying(song2)
            {
               //play song 2
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(fast, pos, Color.White);
        }
        if(stateS == "slow")
        {
            if(MediaPlayer.IsPlaying(song3)
            {
               //do nothing  
            }
            if(!MediaPlayer.IsPlaying(song31)
            {
               //play song 3
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(slow, pos, Color.White);
        }
```

Sadly, I have not found any way to do this, as there is no way I have found to see if a specific song is playing. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can track all your sounds by marking the time when each sound starts playing using a dictionary of timespans:

```
Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> SoundStartTimeDic;
```

Populate the dictionary's key-value pair every time a sound starts playing with its name as the key and the current game time as value, like so:

```
SoundStartTimeDic[mySound.Name()] = gameTime;
```

Then you can see if the difference between current time minus sound start time is greater than the duration of the sound:

```
if (gameTime.TotalMilliseconds -
     SoundStartTimeDic[mySound.Name()].TotalMilliseconds >
     mySound.Duration.TotalMilliseconds)
{ /* yes, the sound has played already */ }
```

---

So I figured you want to play your sound again after it ends. And you are using `MediaPlayer` for some reason.

You can either use `System.Media.SoundPlayer`:

```
SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer("path");
sound.PlayLooping();
```

Or do it XNA way:

```
SoundEffect bgmusic;
bgmusic = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("path");
SoundEffectInstance instance = bgEffect.CreateInstance();
instance.IsLooped = true;
bgEffect.Play();
```

Comment: Not exactly, I wish to check if a song(song1) is currently playing. There is a MediaState property that returns whether or not a song is currently playing, just not in specifics.

Comment: Well, this method can work with anything that has measurable duration, so... You should really add more context when stating your problem. The specifics, the environment, your research. You know, things that help better understand your problem and find maybe not the most obvious solutions.

Comment: I just made an edit, hopefully it clears things up. I do agree that I gave far too little information

Comment: The reason I am using MediaPlayer is I wish to play a song, not a sound effect.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, song is a derived class of sound ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using another Song variable, which I named Playing, I set the song which I wished to be played to it, and played it. Example:

```
        if (stateS == "normal")
        {
            if (!MediaPlayer.Equals(playing, normS))
            {
                playing = normS;
            }

            spriteBatch.Draw(norm, pos, Color.White);
        }
        else if (stateS == "fast")
        {
            if (!MediaPlayer.Equals(playing, fastS))
            {
                playing = fastS;
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(fast, pos, Color.White);
        }
        else if (stateS == "slow")
        {
            if (!MediaPlayer.Equals(playing, slowS))
            {
                playing = slowS;
            }
        }
```